# Any modifications i should do on this class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm working on a class diagram of a simple project.

Here's a basic description of it:

"usuario" is the 'user class'. From it, i can have "membro_coral, "Membro_comissao" and "Administrador".  "membro_coral" can post some news on the web site, but it goes through an avaliation to see if it can be posted or not. "Membro_coral" has a "perfil" associated with it.

There's the "evento" class. It's a class for mapping events. Users can give their disponibilities to attend to some events. And "escalacoes_disponibilidades" is the junction table.

I've added Three classes corresponding to the "Perfil" values. Some people are "membro_comissao", some people are "membro_coral" and actualy, only one is the "Administrador".

Is this class diagram right? Any modifications i should do?

EDIT: i've update my class diagram. I've added the "Status_Noticia" class. It's associated with noticia. I've done this in order to improve the statemachine diagram of "Noticia" (there's an use case which an user can send news to de displayed, but it goes through an avaliation process).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly correct. There are some minor observations however:

- Membro_comissao, Membro_coral and Administrator are kind of users, right? If so, you should do one of the following: a) derive all 3 classes form user, or b) create a new class (enumerator) TipoUsuario, with those 3 values. Which option to implement depends on if there are some special features that make the 3 different one from another (some different attributes, methods or maybe associations (see the next point)
- You said: " "Membro_coral" has a "perfil" associated with it.". Than this class should be associated with PErfil and not otherwise. This could be a reason to apply the option a) from before. This association should be a normal assoc. and not a composition

So, the main decision you must take is how to model user types.

Comment: Atually i was mistaken. It's "usuário" who's associated with "Perfil" and not "membro_coral". I thought of including those classes for the future, if different attributes, methods are specific to each one of them.

Comment: I've updated my class diagram. Could you please check it out Aleks?

Comment: Looks better. A bit of fine tunning though. - Loose up your multiplicities, there is no reason not to use 0..n somethimes (it is more realistic and more flexible). For example between Usuario and Noticia - it is ok that Noticia has 1 User, but why should user mandatory have min. 1 Noticia? This is surely untrue. The same with Perfil, Status_noticia, etc. So, reconsider your multiplicities and use 0..1 or 0..n whenever possible. - Don't use foreign keys in class diagrams, as they are assumed. For example in the association class you do not need IDs of two classes it connects.

Comment: Oooh...i see. I'll add these modifications. Thanks for the help Aleks!